# Dropdown Value selected not changing when option selected changes Java Script

Tags: javascript

Following is Html for Drop down

```
<select name="fancySelect" onchange="test()" class="makeMeFancy" id="drop1">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1" data-icon="assets/images/large/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt">BTC<span class="select_coin_button_arrow">▾</span></option>
            <option value="1" data-icon="assets/images/small/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt" >BTC</option>
            <option value="17" data-icon="assets/images/small/ether.png" data-html-text="ETH&lt;i&gt;">ETH</option>  
</select>
```

and following is js function test()

```
function test() {           
    var e = document.getElementById("drop1");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    console.dir(strUser)
}
```

How to Print

Follwing is Jquery Script working on Dropdown

As code is working without Jquery Script,There seems to be problem 
in following JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // The select element to be replaced:
    var select = $('select.makeMeFancy');

    var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>', {
        width: select.outerWidth(),
        className: 'tzSelect',
        html: '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
    });

    var dropDown = $('<ul>', {className: 'dropDown'});
    var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');

    // Looping though the options of the original select element

    select.find('option').each(function (i) {
        var option = $(this);

        if (i == select.attr('selectedIndex')) {
            selectBox.html(option.text());
        }

        // As of jQuery 1.4.3 we can access HTML5 
        // data attributes with the data() method.

        if (option.data('skip')) {
            return true;
        }

        // Creating a dropdown item according to the
        // data-icon and data-html-text HTML5 attributes:

        var li = $('<li>', {

            html: '<img src="' + option.data('icon') + '" /><span>' +
            option.data('html-text') + '</span>'
        });

        li.click(function () {

            selectBox.html(option.text());
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

            // When a click occurs, we are also reflecting
            // the change on the original select element:
            select.val(option.val());
            return false;
        });

        dropDown.append(li);
    });

    selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
    select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

    // Binding custom show and hide events on the dropDown:

    dropDown.bind('show', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.addClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideDown();

    }).bind('hide', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideUp();

    }).bind('toggle', function () {
        if (selectBox.hasClass('expanded')) {
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

        }
        else dropDown.trigger('show');
    });

    selectBox.click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('toggle');
        return false;
    });

    // If we click anywhere on the page, while the
    // dropdown is shown, it is going to be hidden:

    $(document).click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('hide');


    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {

    // The select element to be replaced:
    var select = $('select.makeMeFancydrop');

    var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>', {
        width: select.outerWidth(),
        className: 'tzSelect',
        html: '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
    });

    var dropDown = $('<ul>', {className: 'dropDown'});
    var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');

    // Looping though the options of the original select element

    select.find('option').each(function (i) {
        var option = $(this);

        if (i == select.attr('selectedIndex')) {
            selectBox.html(option.text());
        }

        // As of jQuery 1.4.3 we can access HTML5 
        // data attributes with the data() method.

        if (option.data('skip')) {
            return true;
        }

        // Creating a dropdown item according to the
        // data-icon and data-html-text HTML5 attributes:

        var li = $('<li>', {
            html: '<img src="' + option.data('icon') + '" /><span>' +
            option.data('html-text') + '</span>'
        });

        li.click(function () {

            selectBox.html(option.text());
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

            // When a click occurs, we are also reflecting
            // the change on the original select element:
            select.val(option.val());
            return false;
        });

        dropDown.append(li);
    });

    selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
    select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

    // Binding custom show and hide events on the dropDown:

    dropDown.bind('show', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.addClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideDown();

    }).bind('hide', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideUp();

    }).bind('toggle', function () {
        if (selectBox.hasClass('expanded')) {
            dropDown.trigger('hide');
        }
        else dropDown.trigger('show');
    });

    selectBox.click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('toggle');
        return false;
    });

    // If we click anywhere on the page, while the
    // dropdown is shown, it is going to be hidden:

    $(document).click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('hide');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#drop1").click(function () {

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for Editing sinisake

Comment: Np, btw, your code is working: https://jsfiddle.net/v2m3ppv6/

Comment: Yes,It is working but with my complete code it isn't. I think there is some error in other part of page. Thanks for JS Fiddle

Comment: So, share complete relevant HTML and javascript, someone will help, for sure. Btw, if you use fancySelect library, your HTML is probably transformed, so you don't have select and option tags anymore....check HTML created by plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, your HTML is completelly changed, by jQuery script you use. Btw, it is very old script, and seems compatible just with older versions of jQuery.... However, instead `<select>` element which is removed, now you have `<ul>` with `.dropDown` class. To get selected value, you can do something like this:

```
$(".dropDown li").click(function () {

console.log($(this).text())

});
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // The select element to be replaced:
    var select = $('select.makeMeFancy');

    var selectBoxContainer = $('<div>', {
        width: select.outerWidth(),
        className: 'tzSelect',
        html: '<div class="selectBox"></div>'
    });

    var dropDown = $('<ul>', {className: 'dropDown'});
    var selectBox = selectBoxContainer.find('.selectBox');

    // Looping though the options of the original select element

    select.find('option').each(function (i) {
        var option = $(this);

        if (i == select.attr('selectedIndex')) {
            selectBox.html(option.text());
        }

        // As of jQuery 1.4.3 we can access HTML5 
        // data attributes with the data() method.

        if (option.data('skip')) {
            return true;
        }

        // Creating a dropdown item according to the
        // data-icon and data-html-text HTML5 attributes:

        var li = $('<li>', {

            html: '<img src="' + option.data('icon') + '" /><span>' +
            option.data('html-text') + '</span>'
        });

        li.click(function () {

            selectBox.html(option.text());
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

            // When a click occurs, we are also reflecting
            // the change on the original select element:
            select.val(option.val());
            return false;
        });

        dropDown.append(li);
    });

    selectBoxContainer.append(dropDown.hide());
    select.hide().after(selectBoxContainer);

    // Binding custom show and hide events on the dropDown:

    dropDown.bind('show', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.addClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideDown();

    }).bind('hide', function () {

        if (dropDown.is(':animated')) {
            return false;
        }

        selectBox.removeClass('expanded');
        dropDown.slideUp();

    }).bind('toggle', function () {
        if (selectBox.hasClass('expanded')) {
            dropDown.trigger('hide');

        }
        else dropDown.trigger('show');
    });

    selectBox.click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('toggle');
        return false;
    });

    // If we click anywhere on the page, while the
    // dropdown is shown, it is going to be hidden:

    $(document).click(function () {
        dropDown.trigger('hide');


    });
});



$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropDown li").click(function () {
   console.log($(this).text())

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="fancySelect" onchange="test()" class="makeMeFancy" id="drop1">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1" data-icon="assets/images/large/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt">BTC<span class="select_coin_button_arrow">▾</span></option>
            <option value="1" data-icon="assets/images/small/bitcoin.png" data-html-text="BTC&lt;i&gt" >BTC</option>
            <option value="17" data-icon="assets/images/small/ether.png" data-html-text="ETH&lt;i&gt;">ETH</option>  
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks BTW,I found another way by using main jquery sheet to manipulate data accordingly.